# how can i stop the rotation of the wheel when opening the file or at the end of the download?

Tags: c#, html, razor

'i wrote this code in cshtml which opens and downloads a pdf file. While I wait for the download the loading wheel appears but it doesn't stop even after opening. Do you have any idea ?'

````
<html>
<head>
    <title>caricamento</title>
    <style>
        .loader {
            border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
            border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
            border-radius: 50%;
            width: 120px;
            height: 120px;
            animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
            margin: 0 auto;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }

        @@keyframes spin {

0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
            100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>caricamento file PDF</h1>
    <div class="loader"></div>

    <script>
        function startDownload() {
            //download del file
            setTimeout(function () {
                // Redirect alla pagina del file da scaricare
                window.location.href = "https://localhost:44394/Carrello/CarrelloDownload";
            }, 3000); // 3000 millisecondi = 3 secondi
        }

        // Chiamata alla funzione di avvio del download quando la pagina è completamente caricata
        //window.onload = startDownload;
        window.startDownload();
    </script>
</body>
</html>```
````